# What does this Scala syntax mean ("= something" after a method)?

Tags: scala

Two examples from the [Scala's blog](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2023/05/30/scala-3.3.0-released.html):

```scala
def canFail(input: String): Try[List[String]] = Try:
  someComputation(input).flatMap: res =>
    val partial = moreComputation(res)
    andEvenMore(partial)
```

and this one:

```scala
import util.boundary, boundary.break

def sumOfRoots(numbers: List[Double]): Option[Double] = boundary:
  val roots = numbers.map: n =>
    println(s" * calculating square root for $n*")
    if n >= 0 then Math.sqrt(n) else break(None)
  Some(roots.sum)
```

In the first example the method returns `Try[List[String]]`. But what is  `= Try`?
And in the second example, `= boundary`... What is it?

Comment: `=` is just how a method definition ends, and starts the expression that is its implementation. Then both `Try:` and `boundary:` are just calling the `apply` method on the relevant object, and the rest is the body of that `apply` invocation. - This is just how the new indentation-based syntax looks like, personally I very much dislike it, but that is another discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example could be rewritten with braces syntax as the following which hopefully is more clear:

```scala
def canFail(input: String): Try[List[String]] = {
  Try {
    someComputation(input).flatMap { res =>
      val partial = moreComputation(res)
      andEvenMore(partial)
    }
  }
}
```

`=` is just the start of method body definition.

In my code above, the first braces are not necessary. Same could be written:

```scala
def canFail(input: String): Try[List[String]] = Try {
  someComputation(input).flatMap { res =>
    val partial = moreComputation(res)
    andEvenMore(partial)
  }
}
```

And then, if you changes braces for the indentation syntax, you get your first code example.

---

As for `Try { ... }`, it's syntactic sugar for `Try.apply { ... }`, itself the same as `Try.apply({ ... })`.